# How to create sidebar in Google Chrome Extension?

Tags: visual-studio, google-chrome-extension

I was looking about creating a sidebar extension in Google Chrome and read that there was a API call, Google disabled it. So maybe anyone know how to create on and has examples of it?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the sidebar API effort was discontinued recently.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=477424

Which means your only option for a Chrome Extension with a sidebar is to inject a sidebar into websites that the user vists. See content scripts:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

Comment: is there any example using content script creating sidebar? I tried to find but most of the examples are using sidebar API, and other examples are not working.