# How to insert sidebar to the left of all kind of webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension, sidebar

I need to insert a sidebar to the left, inside the current page, to show output. Insertion should not hide the main page,

[image]

rather, it should squeeze or adjust, showing all content.

Problem is, [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72677798/11974735) I got does not apply to **all type of webpage**, is there a way to insert sidebar the way I described?

Thanks.

Comment: Plz see the following comment to understand the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72649340/how-to-insert-sidebar-inside-the-current-page-to-show-output/72677798#comment128378907_72677798

Comment: It's unlikely you'll be able to make this work for all pages without comprehensively updating the page's CSS and tracking all style changes to the page.

Comment: @Ouroborus Is the number of variation large? I am not experienced, so I don't know, but if there are a few number of ways, then we can check, and take necessary step programmatically.

Comment: Instead of doing it that way, you could always have a BUTTON float to the left of the screen that when pressed it will slide the panel out above the website. Then the button can be pressed and the panel will slide back in.

Comment: @imvain2 The sidebar will contain some text which will be compared with the text of current tab, if some part is hidden (of the current tab) when the sidebar is  on by clicking button, the extension becomes pointless :(

Comment: Hope this link will help your constraint https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_sidebar_shift.

Comment: can the main page load in an iframe?

Comment: @David not educated enough in JavaScript to understand what you said, kindly elaborate.

Comment: Iframe is an html-element and explained here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Comment: @David the link is not required, one can google, your question is not concrete, if you're asking whether we can inject/insert iframe in to current page, then answer is, probably no, possible issue is, inserting local HTML as iframe to a webpage, which is not on same server

Comment: No actually it would be the sidebar on the same server and the foreign page would load in an iframe.

Comment: @David something like that... but note the question is regarding a Chrome extension, the HTML inside iframe will local file....

Comment: @David unfortunately the iFrame idea would also not work for the OP, as a lot of websites have a Cross-Origin Security Policy that prohibits them being displayed in an iFrame

Comment: @AaronMeese  yes, I realized it, and that wouldn't be the only problem.

Comment: I think you can use devtools extension as a work around

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there could be a truly universal solution, but I hope I can support as much cases as possible with my [`createDockedSidebar` function](https://git.kaki87.net/KaKi87/universal-docked-sidebar/src/branch/master/mod.js).

It takes the following parameters :

- `parentElement` is the one in which the sidebar will be mounted (`body` by default) ;
- `element` is the sidebar itself (a newly created `div` by default) ;
- `size` is the width/height of the sidebar (required `number`) ;
- `placement` is either `left`, `top`, `right` or `bottom` (`left` by default) ;
- `strategy` is the approach used to make space for the sidebar :

  - `margin` & `padding` apply either to `parentElement`
  - `children-margin` & `children-padding` apply either to all children of `parentElement`
  - `children-transform` applies `translateX`/`translateY` to all children of `parentElement`
  - `container` moves all children of `parentElement` another element ;
- `container` is the element in which all children of `parentElement` are moved when using the `container` strategy.

`children-transform` & `container` are the only strategies that may support `top` & `bottom` values for `placement`.

On Wikipedia, `container` is the only strategy that will work properly. Luckily, it's a server-side rendered website.

Indeed, client-side rendered websites have higher chances of breaking this mode, as they might move elements back to their original position, especially during navigation. Although [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) might help overcoming this on PWAs, they would probably become unstable.

More tests :

- on StackOverflow, all strategies but `container` work, although `children-margin` is the only one that will handle the header ;
- on MDN, all strategies will work except top/bottom placements ;
- on Google, all strategies except `container` will work for left placement and none will work for top/right/bottom placements ;
- on GitHub and Reddit (old), all strategies except top/bottom placements and right placement for `children-transform` will work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort, to test your code, plz adjust it according to the `content.js` from this link (the source of the problem): https://stackoverflow.com/q/72649340/11974735 thank you.

Comment: I don't understand what adjustment do you need 

Comment: I'm guessing you'd replace `view.document.body.appendChild(edit)` with `createDockedSidebar({ parentElement: view.document.body, element: edit })`.

Comment: Please share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your extension that I could run on my browser.

Comment: I misunderstood your code : the `parentElement` parameter should not be specified, and the `view` variable can be removed.

Comment: Please share a reproducible demonstration using the `content.js` given in the above link.

Comment: Unfortunately, your code could not be awarded the bounty as you failed to demonstrate... suggestion is, delete this answer, post with proper demonstration in the original post linked by OP, according to that context, and ping me, I might award bounty declaring exclusively for you,  provided that it is working.